# Format date string in Linux

Tags: date

I have a date string format: %d%m%y  e.g `220316` 22nd March 2016

I would like to be able to convert this format so that it displays as `2016-03-22` %Y-%m-%d

I tried supplying the date with current format, and specifying the targeted format however I have been unsuccessful.

```
date -d '280317 %d%m%y' '+%Y%m%d'
```

Comment: In general, you should indicate which Linux shell you're using. It's probably `bash` but Linux has other shells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
x="220316"
out="20$(echo $x | cut -c5-6)-$(echo $x | cut -c3-4)-$(echo $x | cut -c1-2)"
```

What this does is concatenates `20`, the element on 5th and 6th place of `$x`, `-`, the element on 3rd and 4th place of `$x`, `-` and finally the first and second element of `$x`, leaving you with `2016-03-22`.